# How to delete the content of the line in a vscode snippet

Tags: vscode-extensions

I've made a vscode extension that has a few snippets. For example this one:

```
    "header4": {
        "prefix": "header 4",
        "body": [
            "[header 4](Text='')"
        ],
        "description": "Write a description for this snippet"
     }
```

When I write he... it shows the snippet and I can click on it. Everything is fine it writes [header4]Text='').
My problem comes when I try to write [he... because I find the snippet but it writes [[header4]Text='')]. I don't want those brackets. I want to delete these brackets. Anyone know how to do that?

I tried to put variables but there is no variable that can help me. I tried to put the command bracketeer.removeBrackets but is not working either.
Any help?
Thank you

Comment: You only want to delete the last `]` at the very end?

Comment: I want to delete the last ] and the first [ @Mark